# How to create new topic with pykafka with partitions and replication?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I want to be able to programmatically create a topic in Kafka using [pykafka](http://pykafka.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  I know that accessing the TopicDict will automatically create a topic if one does not exist but I don't know how to control the number of partitions/replicas with that.  Also, it has a nasty bug where it ends up in an infinite loop if Kafka goes down.  Basically I want to do something like the following:

```
create_topic('mytopic', partitions=2, replicas=3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Pykafka is a Python implementation of Kafka producer and consumer API, what you want to achieve is an operation that in Kafka is performed using another API, the administration/operations API (actually a group of Java classes). I don't think Pykafka has an API/wrapper for that.
What you may be observing is a topic being automatically created by Kafka. What you can do is to configure using properties the default number of partitions and replicas for automatically created topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `subprocess`

If you install [Kafka binaries](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/1.0.0/kafka_2.11-1.0.0.tgz), you can do something like this

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient
import subprocess

client = KafkaClient(hosts="localhost:9092")

subprocess.Popen("PATH/TO/KAFKA/BINARY/kafka_2.11-1.0.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic testtopic --replication-factor 1 --partitions 10".split())
```